# Could anyone help me getting glutBitmapString to work?

Tags: c++, string, opengl, bitmap, glut

I'm messing around with glutBitmapString from the OpenGlut library. Right now I just want to write a string on the screen to make sure it works, but I cannot get it to appear:

```
const char* texto = "texto";
glRasterPos2i(100, 120);
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10, (UCHAR*)texto);
```

I've also tried with glutBitmapCharacter in a for loop, but with no success. Could someone give me a clear example or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`glRasterPos()` positions are transformed by the current projection/modelview matrices.  Make sure they're reasonable.

Or use `glWindowPos2i()` to bypass them.

Example:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glOrtho( 0, w, 0, h, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    const char* texto = "texto";
    glRasterPos2i( 100, 120 );
    glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10, (const unsigned char*)texto );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 300, 300 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```